# Is it good idea to clone cakephp model objects?

Tags: php, cakephp

How can I use cake's model object for me to be able to do this in a controller:

```
$User1->doThis();
$User2->doThis();
```

$User1 and $User2 are the clones of the User Model.

Are there any unforeseen consequences if I keep cloning model objects?

Are there better ways? I just find it a bit difficult to go back and forth to work with different entities on the same model object.

Thanks.

Comment: Do `$User1` and `$User2` represent different users? If so, I don't see problems

Comment: Just curious, how can model objects hold two different users?

Comment: @galymzhan Yes each new model object represents a different user. I was just worried of any unintended consequences when I change property of one object. I don't know cake model object that well, and if cloning will truly make them independent objects.

Answer (score 1):

Probably not a good idea. I can't back this up with experiments, this is just my gut feeling. It just seems like a bad idea.

You do have to ask yourself: is this really something not solvable by other means? A simple for(each) loop? Custom methods in the model? Refactoring?

Comment: Yes there are other way... but I want to have this as an option. If anybody has tried it before and failed, I want to know. I have the feeling that it might now work, so asking for opinions. Thanks anyways.